# Synaptics touchpad settings won't apply/save

Tags: drivers, windows-10-preview, synaptics-touchpad

I just installed the Windows 10 Technical Preview, and I'm going through the usual driver issues.  I had this problem on Windows 8 as well, and I can't remember what I did to fix it.

When I attempt to change the Synaptics touchpad settings, clicking `Apply` or `OK` reverts all of my changes--immediately, not after a restart.

I recall needing to apply some sort of fix to get the settings to save.  The fix wasn't too hackish, and it was permanent.  Any ideas?  I've mucked around in the registry, but nothing popped out at me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling the driver seems to have worked.  It's possible that simply resetting the device would've had a similar effect.